# Limit of $\sin x$ as $x$ tends to infinity

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I understand that $-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$ for any real $x$. However, the function oscillates and doesn't approach a finite limit as $x$ tends to infinity.

So, what is the mathematically correct statement: the limit is undefined, the limit is indeterminate or the limit approaches infinity?

Further, are the concepts of indeterminate, undefined and infinity different? The terms seem to be used interchangeably though.

Note: I've read the answers on similar posts [Limit approaching infinity of sine function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52371/limit-approaching-infinity-of-sine-function?rq=1) and [Is limit of $\sin x$ at infinity finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996370/is-limit-of-sin-x-at-infinity-finite) but couldn't find answers specific to my doubt.

Comment: There is no limit in the neighborhood of $\infty $ (or it diverges at $+\infty $)

Comment: My preferred term is: the limit "*does not exist*.

Comment: @stinking bishop: are the terms "does not exist" and "approaches infinity" interchangeable? For example, the limit of 1/x as x tends to 0 does not exist, but we also say the limit approaches infinity. Is that incorrect?

Comment: I use "does not exist" when it does not fit any of the other cases where the limit can be *said* to "be"/"be equal to" something in the given context. (a) In some context you would only consider finite limits, (b) in another context the limit you analyse would be either finite, or $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, (c) in yet another context it could be finite or $\infty$ (without defined sign of the infinity) etc.

Comment: (Cont'd) So, for $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ you can in the context (a) and (b) say that it does not exist, and in context (c) it does exist and it *is* $\infty$. I would *not* say that the "limit approaches infinity": informally, the *function* "approaches infinity", and the limit *is* infinity in the third case.

Answer (score 2):

There are no "indeterminate limits", only indeterminate forms. An infinite limit has a specific meaning, in that the function is eventually greater or smaller than any finite number. Since the sine does not exhibit this behaviour, its limit at infinity is undefined.

Comment: Thank you. I have a follow up question: if the limit of sine is undefined around infinity, why is $sin x/x$ not an indeterminate form as x approaches infinity? L'hopital is not applicable here, so is "limit is undefined" different from "approaching infinity"?