# Can we use the Final Value Theorem to evaluate $\lim_{t \to \infty} {\sin(t)}$?

Tags: limits, laplace-transform

I was reading about the Final Value Theorem for Laplace Transforms. It states that for if a function $f(t)$ in continuous time has Laplace Tranform $F(s)$, then:

$$\lim_{t \to \infty}{f(t)} = \lim_{s \to 0}{sF(s)}$$

If we let $f(t) = \sin(t)$, then we get:

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty}{\sin(t)} = \lim_{s \to 0}{\frac{s}{s^2+1}}$$

By L'hopital's rule, the RHS evaluates to:

$$\lim_{s \to 0}{\frac{s}{s^2+1}} = \lim_{s \to 0}{\frac{1}{2s + 1}} = 1$$
which results in:

$$\lim_{t \to \infty}{\sin(t)} = 1$$

Is this a valid conclusion? If not, where is the flaw in my logic? Thanks in advance

Comment: The derivative of $s^2+1$ is not $2s+1$.

Comment: $ \lim_{x \to \infty}{\sin(x)} $ cannot be determined

Comment: L'Hopital's rule only works when a limit has a $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ indeterminant form. $s/(s^2+1)$ clearly has limit $0$ as $s \to 0$, so you cannot apply L'Hopital here (even ignoring that you did it wrong in the first place).

Besides, as with many things of this nature, I imagine there's an implied "this equality holds only if both limits exist," whereas $\sin(x)$ can be proved to not have a limit as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: In fact, as stated [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem#Final_Value_Theorem_using_Laplace_Transform_of_the_Derivative) both limits must exist to begin with. If each limit can be shown to exist and all other conditions are met, then you know (without calculating the limits) that, in fact, both limits are equal. That is what the theorem says. Since sine's limit doesn't exist, you cannot use the Final Value Theorem here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One version of the final value theorem states that if $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$ have Laplace transforms that exist for $s>0$ AND if $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ exists and  $\lim_{s\to0}sF(s)$ exists, then $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\lim_{s\to0}sF(s)$.

Clearly $\lim_{t\to\infty}\sin(t)$ fails to exist ([This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52371/limit-approaching-infinity-of-sine-function)).

---

Another version states if every pole of $F(s)$ is either in the open left-half plane or at the origin, and that $F(s)$ has at most a single pole at the origin, then $\lim_{s\to0}sF(s)=\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$.

Clearly, the poles of $F(s)=\frac1{s^2+1}$ are at $s=\pm i$ and are not in the left half plane.  Hence, the theorem does not apply and we cannot infer equality of the limits.

---

Aside, $\lim_{s\to0}\frac{s}{s^2+1}=0$.  L'Hospital's Rule does not apply since the limit is not of indeterminate form (i.e., $0/0$).

---

> **There are other, more "powerful," versions of the [final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem#Final_value_theorems_for_the_Laplace_transform).**

Comment: This answer is excellent. If I may suggest, after noting that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \sin(t)$ does not exist, explicitly point observe that we “therefore cannot apply this version of the Final Value Theorem”.